# Angular directive showing in the wrong place

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have the following page

```
<body ng-controller="myController">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="r in rows">
                <div show-row></div>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
```

with the following Angular module

```
ng.module('myModule', [ ])
    .controller('myController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
        $scope.rows = [a non-empty array of values]
    }]).directive('showRow', function () {
        return {
            replace: true,
            template: '<td>Hello!</td>'
        };
    });
```

My problem is that `Hello!` is shown once before the table and not, as I would expect, once for every row of the table.
I guess I have to use the scope property for the directive, but how?

Comment: use <td show-row/> instead and remove replace:true in drective

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with `div` which cannot be a children to tr. Change the `div` to `td`.

```
<body ng-controller="myController">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="r in rows">
                <td show-row></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
```

Comment: I'm not sure why this answer was downvoted. It fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a similar problem with the following layout:

```
<table>
    <table-header data="headers" order="order"></table-header>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="...">
             ...
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The tableHeader directive looks like this:

```
.directive('tableHeader', [function () {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    scope: {
        data: '=',
        order: '='
    },
    template: '\
        <thead><tr> \
            <th ng-repeat="header in ::data" \
                ng-click="orderBy(header)"> \
                {{:: header.name }} \
            </th> \
        </tr></thead>',
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {           
        scope.orderBy = function (header) {
            if (scope.order.by === header.prop) {
                scope.order.reverse = !scope.order.reverse;
            } else {
                scope.order.by = header.prop;
            }
        };
    }
};
```

Weird enough, the thead element ends up out of the table, instead of inside.

**Edit**: seems to be documented in https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/7295.